# Can computers recieve data wirelessly without being powered?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, electrical-engineering, computer

I'm not sure if this question totally fits here, but I think this is the best SE for it.

Traditionally, to connect to the internet (a server), a computer must be *on*: powered and running. This means that the computer requires the circuit within the actual machine to be connected (the battery inside cannot be off).

But is it possible to passively receive data in a peer to peer environment? For example, if Alice's computer is asleep, but Bob wants to send her a message P2P, he can send the message.

This question basically boils down to
"Do light signal receivers require an electrical current to be active?"

Comment: All signals have power. The RFID chip in a credit card operates on power that it harvests from the signal that interrogates it. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently, most cameras had no batteries.  They received light signals that carried information, and they stored that information on film.

Comment: Oh, interesting analogy. So there would need to be an analogue component to Alice's machine. Seems obvious thinking back on it.

But I don't think this would work with very long distances, right?

Comment: I am sure there are many pictures of the moon taken with non-powered cameras.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the receiver must be powered and online to receive. But you could send the power wirelessly too.

Comment: Wait, can you send power (to power an inactive receiver) wirelessly? That would be crazy; do you have a link to a method for this?

Comment: Old crystal radios do not attempt to amplify the radio signal nor the audio output and can just run off the transmission power. But no, I meant something like wireless charging. I do not know what it is you want to do.